# Postgres, select with if condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

In a db I have a json string that can contains different types of account status (unfortunately we can't change structure of table). 2 examples:

```
"status": "account blocked. Reason test"

"status": "suspended 1544724336657"
```

The question is, it is possible to check if status is suspended and separate "suspended" from timestamp and convert this timestamp to date? And return it as type|suspended until|1544724336657? It's easy to take whole value of status but when I try add if statement I got an error. I tried to do it in that way:

```
select 
  id, 
  if (status::jsonb->'status')::text 
      like '%suspended%' then split_part(status::jsonb->'status'::text, ' ', 1) status, 
  split_part(status::jsonb->'status'::text, ' ', 2) until else 
  status::>jsonb->'status' status end if 
where 
  status is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing current timestamp:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN split_part('suspended 1544725347', ' ', 1) = 'suspended' THEN
    to_timestamp( cast( split_part('suspended 1544725347', ' ', 2) as double precision) )
  END
```